# Is there a readymade script that I can use to automate sync of server level logins, roles and securable permissions between 2 SQL servers?

Tags: sql-server, security, log-shipping

I have configured log shipping from SQL1 to SQL2.

Database level users, roles and securable permissions are getting transferred. However suppose the user doesn't exist on the server level login, then that user cannot connect to the db (on SQL2).

I am manually applying this script (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/security/transfer-logins-passwords-between-instances) every few weeks to sync the logins, roles and securable permissions. I have to strip off the users that already exist so that the script doesn't error.

I want to automate this by using a sql agent job so that server level logins, roles and securable permissions are synced between SQL1 and SQL2 (and preferably the login is atleast disabled (or even better deleted) if it is deleted from the source server SQL1. Is there any ready made solution for this?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [PowerShell ❤ SQL Server](https://dbatools.io) (dbatools.io) and then possibly the video they posted on their site: [Watch a SQL Server to SQL Server Migration](https://youtu.be/hg8tovMRX2k). Your question is currently a bit of a shopping list question and might be closed.

Comment: The requirement to sync server level login, roles and securable permissions is a basic question in log shipping environment and unfortunately there is no simple answer on SO

Comment: Try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/70779202/14868997 you can run it as a Agent Job. It only does server level logins and roles, but you  should be able to modify it. Then execute it via linked server `EXEC LinkedServer.YourDB.sys.sp_executesql @sql`